# Wicket: How to add link address in runtime

Tags: java, wicket

Does somebody know how can I dynamically add link address in Wicket?

Comment: Most things in Wicket are pretty dynamic.  I think maybe we need more context here.  Show some code where you want to add something and give some idea of what you're trying to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExternalLink` takes a model parameter that supplies a link URL. That model can be pretty much anything. Here's one that generates random links (`LoadableDetachableModel` is a convenience implementation of a dynamic model):

```
IModel<String> model=new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    @Override
    protected String load() {
        // this class does not really exist
        return LinkRandomizer.getNewRandomUrl();
    }
};
add(new ExternalLink("link", model));
```

See:

- [Working with Wicket Models](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/working-with-wicket-models.html)
- [Using Wicket Labels and Links](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2008/10/using-wicket-labels-and-links.html)
- [ExternalLink API docs](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/ExternalLink.html)
- [LoadableDetachableModel API docs](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/model/LoadableDetachableModel.html)

---

It turns out the OP needs a `ListView` with `ExternalLink`s.

Here is a Panel with a list of links:

```
public class FooPanel extends Panel {

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    public static class LinkBean{
        private String link;
        private String label;
        public LinkBean(final String link, final String label) {
            this.link = link;
            this.label = label;
        }
        public String getLabel() {
            return this.label;
        }
        public String getLink() {
            return this.link;
        }
        public void setLabel(final String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }
        public void setLink(final String link) {
            this.link = link;
        }


    }

    public FooPanel(final String id) {
        super(id);
        this.add(new ListView<LinkBean>("item", 
                Arrays.asList(
                    new LinkBean("http://www.google.com/","Google"), 
                    new LinkBean("http://www.ebay.com/", "Ebay"))
                ) {

            private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final ListItem<LinkBean> item) {
                item.add(new ExternalLink("link", item.getModelObject().getLink())
                    .add(new Label("label",item.getModelObject().getLabel()))
                );

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the associated HTML:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<wicket:panel>
    <div class="linkItem" wicket:id="item">
        <a href="" wicket:id="link" >
            <wicket:container wicket:id="label" />
        </a>
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
</body></html>
```

The Output will be something like this:

```
<div class="linkItem"><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></div>
<div class="linkItem"><a href="http://www.ebay.com/">Ebay</a></div>
```

See

- [ListView and other repeaters](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/listview-and-other-repeaters.html) (an
  ancient tutorial, careful: this
  relates to the older non-generic
  version of ListView in 1.3.x)
- [Wicket Examples: Repeater Views](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/repeater/)
  (ListView is not covered, but the
  handling is pretty identical)
- [ListView Api docs](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListView.html)
- [Wicket in Action](http://www.manning.com/dashorst/) (A very good
  book about Wicket you should consider buying)

Comment: I need to add ExternalLink within ListView in the runtime. Your code is useful, but I still can't get the idea how to do that...